# Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details source error db.SaveChanges();

Tags: c#, sql-server, html, ef-code-first, asp.net-mvc-5

First of all , I am  using Entity Framework Code First From Database MVC5 /C#.
I would like to add new user but when I tried to add e-mail I got error.

Here is my controller method :

```
      [HttpPost]
      public ActionResult InsertUser(Users users, string radioActive) 
    { 
            Users newuser = new Users();
            newuser.username = users.username;
            newuser.password = users.password;
            newuser.name = users.name;
            newuser.mail = users.mail;
            if (radioActive == "on") newuser.isActive = true;
            else newuser.isActive = false;

            db.Users.Add(newuser);
            db.SaveChanges();

      return Redirect(Url.Content("~/Administrate/"));
    }
```

The problem is db.SaveChanges(); I dont understand why but all of my values return well except email.Email return null and I am getting his error.

Also here is my view :

```
      <div class="panel panel-primary">
            <div class="panel-heading text-center">KULLANICI EKLE</div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <form data-toggle="validator" role="form" action="~/Administrate/InsertUser" method="post">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="username" class="control-label">Kullanıcı Adı</label>
                        <input type="text"  class="form-control" id="username" name="username"placeholder="Lütfen kullanıcı adını giriniz." required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="password" class="control-label">Şifre</label>
                        <div class="form-inline row">
                            <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
                                <input type="password" name="password" pattern="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{6,}"  class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Şifre" required>
                                <div class="help-block">Şifreniz ez bir sayı,bir büyük ve bir küçük harf içermeli ve minimum 6 karakterden oluşmalıdır.</div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
                                <input type="password" class="form-control" name="passwordConfirm" id="passwordConfirm" data-match="#password" data-match-error="Şifreniz eşleşmiyor" placeholder="Şifre Tekrar" required>
                                <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="name" class="control-label">Çalışan Adı Soyadı</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Lütfen adınızı ve soyadınızı giriniz." required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="email" class="control-label">Email</label>
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" data-error="Email adresi geçerli değil." required/>
                        </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="radio">
                            <label>
                                <input type="radio"  id ="isActive" name="radioActive" required>
                                Aktif
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="radio">
                            <label>
                                <input type="radio" id="isActive" name="radioActive" required>
                                Pasif
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="groupID" class="control-label">Grup Adı</label>
                        <select class="form-control" name="groupID" id="groupID" required>
                            <option selected disabled  >Lütfen Grubunuzu seçiniz</option>
                            @foreach (var item in ViewData["Gruplar"] as IList<WebApplication1.Models.Groups>)
                            {
                                <option value="@item.id">@item.groupName</option>
                            }
                        </select>
                    </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Kullanıcıyı Kaydet</button>
                            </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I am using MSSQL Server 17 and email's data type is varchar(50)in my table.How can I fix this problem and return email doesnt null. I am new at coding and also MVC5 so if you can help me I am so thankfull.

Comment: Check inner exception part from the error, something went wrong was described there.

Comment: You call the field `mail` in your controller, but `email` in your view. Maybe try removing an `e` in your view?

Comment: Also this input tag seems showing typo: `<input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" ... />`. It should match with model property name: `<input type="email" class="form-control" name="mail" id="mail" ... />`

Comment: Oh, thanks both of you for helping. I dont know how can't I see that mistakes. I am a bit embarrassed. Thank you again. @oerkelens

Comment: and @TetsuyaYamamoto

Answer (score 0):

for "EntityValidationErrors":
You have to check the database table, the name of table columns must be exactly same name with the view element names (if database table column "Email" -> view email element must be "Email" also).
else it will returns "EntityValidationErrors".